# How to get MAM message ID of sent messages?

Tags: xmpp

I am using eJabberd server (MAM enabled) with client library Strophe.js. Client app is storing fixed amount of the messages in local storage.

All the messages, that I receive from the server include elements `<archived/>` and `<stanza-id/>`, which provide server-side generated IDs:

```
<message 
    xmlns="jabber:client" to="aaa@example.net/8667085700924567016834" from="aaa@example.net">
    <result 
        xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" id="1520510373346685">
        <forwarded 
            xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0">
            <message 
                xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="bbb@example.net" from="aaa@example.net/60965696931000870402419" type="chat">
                <archived 
                    xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp" by="aaa@example.net" id="1520510373346685"/>
                <stanza-id 
                    xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" by="aaa@example.net" id="1520510373346685"/>
                <body>asdf</body>
            </message>
            <delay 
                xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="example.net" stamp="2018-03-08T11:59:33.346685Z"/>
        </forwarded>
    </result>
</message>
```

I use these IDs to get fixed amount of messages on each MAM call (using RSM paging - before/after/max attributes). For example:

```
params = {
    "before": "1520510373346685",
    "max": 10,
    onMessage: <some handler>,
    onComplete: <some handler>,
}
this.connection.mam.query(Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(this.myJid), params);
```

This gets me 10 messages before the message with stanza-id `1520510373346685`.

However, the messages I **send** inherently do not have this ID, until I send them and retrieve from MAM.

I did not find any examples on getting the currently sent message ID from the server, and the Strophe does not provide any callbacks after the message was sent from the client and received by the server.

So, the question - is there any way to get the server-generated message ID (stanza-id/archived) for the currently sent message?

Maybe my own approach is wrong - should I generate my own IDs and add it to each message from the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no mechanism specified besides querying the archive. One prominent idea within the XMPP community  to solve this in the future is to reflect the send carbon back to the original sender, which would include a stanza-id element with the ID assigned by the archive.

Comment: Thank you, @Flow. As a solution to this, could I use my own ID on each message as an attribute (in the inner message stanza)? Or this is not recommeded?

Comment: How is that a solution? You want to know the ID the archive assigned, which you don't know a-priori (which the current specification).

Comment: Sorry, it certainly is not :D but it solves the problem (which I did not mention) of avoiding duplicate messages between cache and the archive, until I query the archive again. Do you know if the send carbon reflection will be implemented any time soon? Or is it just currently only a TODO in the XMPP standard?

Comment: It's an ongoing discussion and not yet (clearly) specified. Please feel encourage to approach the XMPP community and get involved. :) A good starting point is xmpp.org and the xsf @muc.xmpp.org MUC.

Comment: Hi, are u able to solve this issue by getting the stanza id of sending message  @Flow